# Highlight separate keywords within a sentence

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two states which stores an array of sentences, suppose say `sentencesHard` state and another stores an array of words, `criticalWords` state. I need to highlight those words from the criticalWords in the sentences of sentencesHard. Right now, it highlights the whole sentence if the sentence contains the word in it, but I need just to highlight that particular word instead of the whole sentence.
For example, "`Configuring` react-redux is `complicated`"

right now, my code looks like this:

```
states={
     criticalWords:["configuring", "complicated"],
     sentencesHard: ["configuring react-redux is complicated"]
}

{this.state.sentencesHard.map((sentence) => (
                <span style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.criticalWords.some(word => sentence.includes(word)) ? '#e4b9b9' : 'initial' }}>
                  {sentence}
                </span>
                ))
              }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your task seems to me a bit more complicated than you may expect, since you need to take care of upper-cased keywords in the beginning of the sentences properly, besides you, most probably, want to keep original punctuation.

So, for class-based components which I assume you use (though I'd prefer function-based), your use case might look something, like:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM

const testKeywords = ['configuring', 'complicated'],
      testSentenses = ['Configuring react-redux, by far, is not complicated, whatsoever.']
      
class Component extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      {
        this.props.sentenses.map(sentense => {
          const blocks = sentense.match(/(\w+|\W)/g)
          return blocks.map(block => 
            this.props.keywords.includes(block.toLowerCase()) ?
            <span style={{backgroundColor: 'grey',color:'white'}}>{block}</span> :
            block
          )
        })
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render (
  <Component sentenses={testSentenses} keywords={testKeywords} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your sentences into individual words:

```
return (
  <>
    {this.state.sentencesHard.map((sentence) => (
      <span>
        {sentence.split(/(\W+)/g).map((word) => (
          <span style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.criticalWords.some(cw => word.includes(cw)) ? '#e4b9b9' : 'initial' }}>
              {word}
          </span>
        )}
      </span>
    ))}
  </>
)
```

Comment: for some reason, it's still highlighting the entire sentence

Answer (score 0):

Add background color to every word in sentence. Like this

```
{
  this.state.sentencesHard.map((sentence) => (
     <span>
      {
       sentence.split(' ').map(word => {
          return this.state.criticalWords.includes(word) ?
                     <span style={{backgroundColor: '#e4b9b9'}}>{word}</span> : word;
       })
      }
     </span>
  ))
}
```

Comment: it did highlight the words, but every word is attached to each other in the sentences, i mean there are no spaces between the words.

Comment: @henrydoe, Hope this helps https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-change-state-tyfwg

Comment: @ManirajMurugan : that solution fails once you find keyword in the beggining of the sentence (with first letter capitalized) or there's a punctuation mark attached to the right of the keyword. Check out [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60185433/11299053) that addresses above issues. Hopefully, you like it (upvotes are appreciated, if so ;)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, I believe your's is a cleaner solution.. Upvoted.. Happy coding !!!..